# Sentry Session Reply not enabled with doc configuration

Tags: sentry

I'm trying to enable session reply for Sentry. I set up my configuration options according to the docs but I'm still getting a message saying they are not enabled when viewing an error in Sentry. Below are is my config:

```
  Sentry.init({
    dsn: '<DSN>',
    environment: env, // production
    release: <release-num>,
    replaysSessionSampleRate: 0.1,
    // If the entire session is not sampled, use the below sample rate to sample
    // sessions when an error occurs.
    replaysOnErrorSampleRate: 1.0,
    integrations: [new Sentry.Replay()],
  });
```

I have `import * as Sentry from '@sentry/react';` imported in this file at version `"@sentry/react": "^7.73.0",`

Here are the docs for reference: https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/session-replay/

Why aren't replays being recorded?